# npx react-native run-ios not working for react native fresh project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

#### Description

Based on the getting started guide provided here https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup, I am trying to build a build a project using react native cli. I followed the exact steps provided in the article and the project starts for android but not for ios. The error I am getting is

```
2022-05-09 19:52:26.204 xcodebuild[27325:198569] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-05-09 19:52:26.208 xcodebuild[27325:198569] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
```

and this

`Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening AwesomeProject.xcworkspace`

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/jaydave5/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-gypcnmvewcvovdgwbdrhxjrrxutt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SysUio.o /Users/jaydave5/Documents/native\ projects/bare\ react\ native/AwesomeProject/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/SysUio.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

On doing some research I saw a stackoverflow post where it said to try opening the xcode workspace in ios folder and trying to build from there I have attached the screenshot of the error I received there

[image]

#### Version

0.68.2

#### Output of `npx react-native info`

```
System:
    OS: macOS 12.2.1
    CPU: (8) x64 Apple M1
    Memory: 43.58 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.17.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.18 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.13 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.03.21.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 15.4, macOS 12.3, tvOS 15.4, watchOS 8.5
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.1 AI-211.7628.21.2111.8193401
    Xcode: 13.3.1/13E500a - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.15 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
    react-native: 0.68.2 => 0.68.2 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

#### Steps to reproduce

Step 1
`npx react-native init AwesomeProject`

Step 2
`npx react-native start`

Step 3
`npx react-native run-ios`

Later I tried creating an app with expo and ejecting it
This is the error I get

```
(warning truncated)
› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » NetOps.cpp

❌  (ios/Pods/Headers/Private/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/Time.h:52:17)

  50 | #define CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID 3
  51 | 
> 52 | typedef uint8_t clockid_t;
     |                 ^ typedef redefinition with different types vs 'enum clockid_t')
  53 | extern "C" int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec* ts);
  54 | extern "C" int clock_getres(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec* ts);
  55 | #endif

› Compiling react-native Pods/RCT-Folly » Format.cpp

⚠️  (/Users/jaydave5/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-fepzfupsfexonsdubhfcgescuowt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Format.dia:1:1)

CompileC /Users/jaydave5/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-fepzfupsfexonsdubhfcgescuowt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Fi...
^ Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error(in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
(warning truncated)

❌  (ios/Pods/Headers/Private/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/Time.h:52:17)

  50 | #define CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID 3
  51 | 
> 52 | typedef uint8_t clockid_t;
     |                 ^ typedef redefinition with different types vs 'enum clockid_t')
  53 | extern "C" int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec* ts);
  54 | extern "C" int clock_getres(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec* ts);
  55 | #endif


⚠️  (/Users/jaydave5/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-fepzfupsfexonsdubhfcgescuowt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FileUtil.dia:1:1)

warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the AwesomeProject editor. (in tar...
^ Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error(in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
(warning truncated)

› 3 error(s), and 3 warning(s)

Failed to build iOS project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code 65.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I am using a M1 based mac book when I ran `pod install` normally it did not work but when I ran `arch-x86_64 pod` install it worked. I would like to point out here that I was not getting any error when I ran `pod install`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have cocoa pods installed you need to `sudo gem install cocoapods`

1. run `cd ios`
2. run `pod install`
3. cd ..  and then delete `build folder`
4. run `react-native run-ios`

if the error persists,

1. delete build folder again
2. open the `/ios` folder in Xcode
3. navigate File -> Project Settings -> Build System -> change (Shared workspace settings and Per-User workspace settings): Build System -> Legacy Build System`

I hope this helps

Comment: I have cocoapods installed,  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod

Comment: have you done the `cd ios && pod install && cd ..` ?